# mongoose aggregation $group with nested object

Tags: mongodb, object, mongoose, grouping, aggregation

I have the following resolver:

```
        const result = await UserPassage.aggregate([
      { $sort: { createdAt: -1 } },
      {
        $group: {
          _id: '$level',
          level: { $first: '$level' },
          passageId: { $first: '$passageId' },
          userId: { $first: '$userId' },
          type: { $first: '$type' },
          category: { $first: '$category' },
          score: { $first: '$score' },
          completedStage: { $first: '$completedStage' },
          userPassageStatsId: {
            _id: { $first: '$_id' },
            stats: {
              readingTime: { $first: '$readingTime' },
              qtdVocab: { $first: '$qtdVocab' },
              qtdTestDone: { $first: '$qtdTestDone' },
              totalQuiz: { $first: '$totalQuiz' },
              progress: { $first: '$progress' },
            },
          },
        },
      },
      { $sort: { level: 1 } },
    ]);

    await UserPassageStats.populate(result, { path: 'userPassageStatsId' });
```

The problem is that I need to populate `'userPassageStatsId'` and return it but it's not working well returning the following error:

```
 MongoError: The field 'userPassageStatsId' must be an accumulator object
```

does anyone knows what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$group` can only contain `_id` or accumulator objects like `$first`, `$last`, `$sum` etc. In your case your building nested object and that syntax is not allowed - accumulator has to be on a top level. You can try two approaches, either return flat structure from `$group` and then reshape using `$project`:

```
{
    $group: {
        _id: '$level',
        level: { $first: '$level' },
        passageId: { $first: '$passageId' },
        userId: { $first: '$userId' },
        type: { $first: '$type' },
        category: { $first: '$category' },
        score: { $first: '$score' },
        completedStage: { $first: '$completedStage' },
        userPassageStatsId_id: { $first: '$_id' },
        readingTime: { $first: '$readingTime' },
        qtdVocab: { $first: '$qtdVocab' },
        qtdTestDone: { $first: '$qtdTestDone' },
        totalQuiz: { $first: '$totalQuiz' },
        progress: { $first: '$progress' }
    }
},
{
    $project: {
        _id: 1,
        level: 1,
        ...,
        userPassageStatsId: {
            _id: "$userPassageStatsId_id",
            stats: {
                readingTime: "$readingTime",
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

or use `$$ROOT` to capture first object for every group and reshape it using `$project`:

```
{
    $group: {
        _id: '$level',
        d: { $first: "$$ROOT" }
    }
},
{
    $project: {
        _id: 1,
        level: "$d.level",
        ...,
        userPassageStatsId: {
            _id: "$d._id",
            stats: {
                readingTime: "$d.readingTime",
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @mickl! thanks for your reply! Now I am getting the following error after apply your  recommendation:

Comment: "message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable field UserPassageStats._id.",
do you have any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: I am populating userPassageStats with:
UserPassageStats.populate(result, { path: 'userPassageStatsId' });

Comment: @GuilhermeRamos the name ends with dot which is not allowed

Comment: ohh not actually just the error message includes the dot by the end of it

Comment: You can add `$lookup` instead of running populate.